# Pattern for executing common code before a property is accessed

Tags: c#

Strictly in interest of saving typing in code, I'd like to find some way to append text to members returned by another class. That probably doesn't make sense, so an example. What I'm working on is a class to manage test data:

```
public class TestFiles
{
    private const string File1RelativePath = @"TestData\File1.xml";
    private const string File2RelativePath = @"TestData\File2.xml";

    private static string RootPath()
    {
        // don't know the deployment location until runtime 
        return Some_DirectoryName_Determined_At_Run_Time_Returned_BySomeOtherModule();
    }

    public static string File1
    {
        get { return Path.Combine(RootPath() + File1RelativePath); }
    }

    public static string File2
    {
        get { return Path.Combine(RootPath() + File2RelativePath); }
    }
}
```

This class does exactly what I want it to, and I can call it simply by :

```
String FileToUseForTest = TestFiles.File1;
```

The problem is that I'm lazy, and when I add more Files I have to do it in 2 places : the constant strings, and the get properties. Maybe I could include the string literal in the getter, but even then I'd have to call Path.Combine(RootPath() ... in each getter, which is far too much work for me.

So, trying another approach, which won't work for reasons shown below:

```
public class TestFiles
{
    public class FileRelativePaths
    {
        private const string File1RelativePath = @"TestData\File1.xml";
        private const string File2RelativePath = @"TestData\File2.xml";
    }

    private static FileRelativePaths relPaths = new RulePackages();

    FileRelativePaths FullPaths
    {
        get { return relPaths; }
    }

    private static string RootPath()
    {
        // No longer called, but somehow need to find a way to append to paths returned in FullPaths
        return Some_DirectoryName_Determined_At_Run_Time_Returned_BySomeOtherModule();
    }
}
```

This almost works, I get the strong typing and a caller could get the files by

```
String FileToUseForTest = TestFiles.FullPaths.File1;
```

But the problem is that this is giving me the relative paths only, where I really wanted to append some code to the strings returned (by using the method RootPath()).

So, is there any way to get this to work, while still having strong typing and keeping the code length to a minimum? I'm a bit resigned to using the first approach above, but thought I'd ask if there was a creative solution.

Comment: Put your file paths in an array or dictionary.  Call one function, passing the test set's number/name. Have that function fix it up.

Comment: If many files, it might be a benefit with code generation. For instance [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd just resign myself to having to change it in two places.  Here is an alternative that I don't like as much, but satisfies your criteria as I understand them:

```
public enum XmlFile{
    File1,
    File2
};

public static class TestFiles{
    const string RelativeDirectory = @"TestData";
    const string XmlExtension = @"xml";
    static string RootPath {
        get
        {
            return Some_DirectoryName_Determined_At_Run_Time_Returned_BySomeOtherModule();
        }
    }

    //overload as necessary for other extensions or pass it as an additional parameter
    public static string GetFullPath(XmlFile file){
        return string.Format(@"{0}{1}\{2}.{3}", RootPath, RelativeDirectory, file, XmlExtension);
    }
}
```

This snippet has some unfortunate side-effects:

- uses convention to associate enum members with a file name
- relies on enum's ToString()
- assumes that the RelativeDirectory is always the same (otherwise, you will need further conventions to accomodate)

Comment: A lot of the replies follow this approach, I'm going to mark this as the answer for discussing the side effects as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about using operator overloading to do an implicit cast which includes the root path?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RelativePath relative = @"Relative\Path\One";

        Console.WriteLine(relative.Path);
        string path = relative;
        Console.WriteLine(path);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class RelativePath
{

    public static string RootPath()
    {
        return @"C:\MyRootPath\";
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public RelativePath(string relativePath)
    {
        this.Path = relativePath;
    }

    public static implicit operator RelativePath(string path)
    {
        return new RelativePath(path);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(RelativePath relativePath)
    {
        return System.IO.Path.Combine(RootPath(), relativePath.Path);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a small helper function...

```
private static string fixupPath (string dir)
{
    return Path.Combine(RootPath() + dir); 

}

public static string File1
{
    get { return fixupPath(File1RelativePath); }
}
```

And use a shorter function name if you really want to optimize keystrokes over maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  Note, untested code ahead:

```
public enum TestFileType {
    File1,
    File2,
}

public class TestFiles
{
    private static Dictionary<TestFileType, String> filePaths = new Dictionary<TestFileType, String> 
        { 
            { TestFileType.File1, @"TestData\File1.xml" }, 
            { TestFileType.File2, @"TestData\File2.xml" } 
        };

    public static String GetFile(TestFileType fType) {
        return Path.Combine(RootPath() + filePaths[fType]);
    }
}

// Use thus: 
TestFiles.GetFile(TestFileType.File1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things spring to mind.  First, instead of having discrete properties, you could have an enumeration, a dictionary, and a single "get" function:

```
public enum TestFile { File1, File2 };

public class TestFiles {

  private static Dictionary<TestFile,string> _testFiles = new Dictionary<TestFile,string> {
    { TestFile.File1, @"TestData\File1.xml" },
    { TestFile.File2, @"TestData\File2.xml" },
  };

  public string RootPath() {
    return @"C:\";
  }

  public string Get( TestFile tf ) {
    return Path.Combine( RootPath(), _testFiles[tf] );
  }

  // even better, you can override the array indexing operator
  public string this[TestFile tf] {
    get { 
        return Path.Combine( RootPath(), _testFiles[tf] );
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to abstract out the repetitive `Path.Combine` code, you could always use a helper class, though I'm dubious that you'd be gaining much here.  Still, it might increase readability:

```
public static class TestFileHelper {
    public static string RootPath() {
      return @"C:\";
    }

    public static string RootedAtTestDir( this string s ) {
        return Path.Combine( RootPath(), s );
    }
}
```

Then, instead of calling `Path.Combine` everywhere, you could just write:

```
return _testFiles[tf].RootedAtTestDir();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be a good use-case for extensions. You can add it to a test assembly/file and just reference it in places where you need it:

```
public static class TestExtensions
{
    private static string RootPath = @"C:\Some\Root\Path";
    public static string AddRoot(this string path)
    {
        return Path.Combine(RootPath, path);
    }
}
```

Another option is to also use a dictionary, in case you have multiple "roots" you want to define, that way you specify two things: the path, and the root key.

```
public static class TestExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> RootPaths = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static void RegisterRoot(string rootKey, string rootPath)
    {
        // Omitted null checking, but should do it.
        RootPaths[rootKey] = rootPath;
    }

    public static string AddRoot(this string path, string rootKey)
    {
        return Path.Combine(RootPaths[rootKey], path);
    }
}
```

Usage is simple. Just call the extension method on any string instance. IE:

```
// Single root version.
TestFiles.File1.AddRoot(); 
// String literal...
@"Relative\Path\File.xml".AddRoot();
// Dictionary root version.
TestExtensions.RegisterRoot("testRoot", @"C:\Some\Test\Directory");
TestFiles.File1.AddRoot("testRoot");
```

Hope that helps.